# Flex/AIR: Native drag'n'drop on sub-application triggers wrong event handlers

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I have two Flex applications (`App1`, `App2`) that I want to use as separate apps (no problem here) but the first app should also be able to load the second app in its window (no problem either). Both apps accept native drag'n'drop (`onDragIn`, `onDragDrop`). However, when I load `App2` as sub-application (multi-versioned) its drag'n'drop handlers are not being called but instead those of `App1`. What am I missing here?

```
<!-- MAIN APP (App1) -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                   creationComplete="onComplete()">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[                  

        import mx.controls.SWFLoader;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        import mx.managers.DragManager;

        internal var app2:App2=null;    
        internal var _show2nd:Boolean=false;            

        protected function onComplete():void
        {
            addEventListener(NativeDragEvent.NATIVE_DRAG_ENTER, onDragIn);
            addEventListener(NativeDragEvent.NATIVE_DRAG_DROP,  onDragDrop);                

            var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
            context.securityDomain = SecurityDomain.currentDomain;
            context.applicationDomain = new ApplicationDomain();

            if (app2 == null) app2 = new App2();
            contentLoader.loadForCompatibility = true;
            contentLoader.loaderContext = context;                 
        }

        private function onDragIn(e:NativeDragEvent):void
        {
            if  (e.clipboard.hasFormat(ClipboardFormats.FILE_LIST_FORMAT) &&
                (e.clipboard.getData(ClipboardFormats.FILE_LIST_FORMAT) as Array).length > 0)   
                    DragManager.acceptDragDrop(this);
        }

        private function onDragDrop(e:NativeDragEvent):void
        {
            var a:Array = e.clipboard.getData(ClipboardFormats.FILE_LIST_FORMAT) as Array;
            (File(a[0]).extension == 'a') ? doThis() : doThat();
        }

        public function get show2nd():Boolean 
        {
            return _show2nd;
        }

        public function set show2nd(b:Boolean):void
        {
            if (!b)
            {
                _show2nd = false;
                contentLoader.unloadAndStop();
                return;
            }

            contentLoader.source = app2;                
            _show2nd = true;
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>    
<s:Button click="{show2nd = !show2nd}"/>
<mx:SWFLoader id="contentLoader"/>
</s:WindowedApplication>

<!-- SUB APP (App2) -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                   creationComplete="onComplete()">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[                  
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        import mx.managers.DragManager;

        protected function onComplete():void
        {
            addEventListener(NativeDragEvent.NATIVE_DRAG_ENTER, onDragIn);
            addEventListener(NativeDragEvent.NATIVE_DRAG_DROP,  onDragDrop);
        }

        private function onDragIn(e:NativeDragEvent):void
        {
            if  (e.clipboard.hasFormat(ClipboardFormats.FILE_LIST_FORMAT) &&
                (e.clipboard.getData(ClipboardFormats.FILE_LIST_FORMAT) as Array).length > 0)   
                    DragManager.acceptDragDrop(this);
        }

        private function onDragDrop(e:NativeDragEvent):void
        {
            var a:Array = e.clipboard.getData(ClipboardFormats.FILE_LIST_FORMAT) as Array;
            (File(a[0]).extension == 'a') ? doThis() : doThat();
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

Comment: It's impossible to tell what's wrong with your code without seeing any of it.  Post an [example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: added a simplified example. `App1` loads `App2` (works fine), but when `App2` is loaded the native drag event handlers of `App1` fire instead of the ones from `App2`.